# Trying to access spreadsheet, Java can't find it in OSX

Tags: java, macos, file-io

I am writing an app which I originally began on a windows machine and have moved it over to my Macbook. The particular issue I'm having is that the app has to load a spreadsheet and access the data within using jexcelapi by after supplying the path to the file and this worked beautifully on my PC with this bit of code:

```
excelWorkbook  = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\My Project\\resources\\CardList.xls"));
```

but now that I have moved it over to my Mac I can't get it to find the file. I tried googling and changing the path to this:

```
excelWorkbook  = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("/Users/loganfernandes/NetBeansProjects/My Project/resources/CardList.xls"));
```

and it just won't work. I've tried many variations of this but I can't seem to figure it out. I even tried making an actual resources folder in the root directory of my project so I can just try the resource path but that's not working for me either.

I keep getting the IO error that the file isn't found and I'm not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: does `stat /Users..../CardList.xls` in a terminal window show anything? If that comes back with a file not found, then it's not a java problem - you've simply got the wrong path.

Comment: Good call. It does come back with "no such file or directory" but I'm not sure how - the directory is copy/pasted from when I right click on the file itself and do "get info" and copy its path, adding only the last bit it doesn't supply which is the file name.

Comment: `cd` into that directory manually, do an `ls`, and see what the filename really is. It could be something silly like `CardList[space].xls`

Comment: Actually, I just did "stat" with that file all the way down the directory tree, adding the CardList.xls to each folder (and subsequently removing it if successful) and the folder it has trouble with is the /My Project/ part of the directory. I'm not super familiar with OSX yet so I wonder, does it struggle with spaces? It seems to have a problem with the space between those two words, returning the no such directory listing with this error "/Users/loganfernandes/NetBeansProjects/My does not exist"

Comment: it will when yhou're doing it at the command line. `ls My Documents` will be trying to ls two files/dirs: `My` and `Documents`, but `ls "My Documents"` will try on just the one. But I doubt this is the problem in your code - you're passing in a single string, and osx should know that. I suppose you could TRY escaping the space: `My\ Project`, but it probably won't help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was with it, but I just removed the space from the directory and it seemed to fix the File IO issue, leaving me with a new one. Now it claims the calls I make to read the worksheet are dereferencing a possible null pointer. Not sure why, they read fine before and actually have data. Odd.